# What does the HTML acronym "span" stands for?

Tags: html, xhtml, tags, semantics, markup

I guess that `<div>` might actually stand for: "division" since it creates a division in the document by separating content before and after it. Am I right?

But `<span>` is a little bit more obscure on its meaning. I made some googling on this and found some interesting options: "Super Passive Analyzer Node", "SPAce Node", "Simple Plain Access Node".

Does anyone know the right acronym for `<span>`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pretty hard to find out what was going on in the minds of the creators of HTML4, where SPAN first appeared. I tracked down the [original draft of the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/), but there is nothing said about the naming, only a definition:

*SPAN is an inline element and can be used within paragraphs, list items,
etc. when you want assign class or language information to a group of words.
SPAN cannot be used to group block-level elements. SPAN has no inherent
effect on rendering until you apply a style, e.g., via a style attribute, or
a linked style sheet.*

It's probably just derived from the verb 'to span'. But I would like to have found a reference:)

**Update**
Also from the HTML4 specification (the [newest one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) this time):

*Each version of HTML has attempted to reflect greater consensus among industry players so that the investment made by content providers will not be wasted and that their documents will not become unreadable in a short period of time.*

Therefore, the SPAN element was probably first supported by a certain browser, after which it was taken over by other browsers and eventually adopted as a standard. So 10 points to the one who can name that browser and produce 199x IRC chat logs of that browser´s devs:)

Comment: I didn't find a browser or the IRC chat logs, but I did find that in the first draft there was something similar to span under a <c> tag<sup>1</sup>.
<p><sub>[1]</sub> A brief history can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span#History "A Brief History")

Answer (score 22):

It's not an acronym, it simply "spans" the content that is within the tag.

Comment: exactly is a term, I visited the wiki is very interesting btw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_(unit)

Answer (score 0):

Span means width and extent of "whatever"

Answer (score -3):

I'm also having this problem of the interpretation of span, but I've tried to translate span and spans as a word to languages I know and I found out that spans could have a similar meaning to embrace, so I guess it can mean that span /span embraces a content, therefore it isolates something which you can format inline.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with that kind of guessings.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.