# Why <span> tag is named so

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the HTML acronym “span” stands for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391520/what-does-the-html-acronym-span-stands-for)

why span tag is named so, can you please tell me why it have this name ?
I searched in google but have not found any explanations...

Comment: Who votes this "not constructive" while there's a perfectly fine duplicate in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a `span` because it is an inline element which can **SPAN** multiple lines (of text). So you can use this in a `<p>` to assign styles to maybe a few words or letters instead of the whole `<p>` (or `div`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it is because it identifies content that SPANs the area between the start and end tag.  Span tags are inline and provide no visual change which follows the definition